# Reconnect to SSH MYSQL workbench on device that's not always online

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ssh

I use workbench on a device that is not always online, every time it goes offline the only way to continue using it is by closing and opening a new connection.

I use SSH connection to access MySQL on remote server,
there is an option by `Query > Reconnect to server`.

but apparently it assumes that the SSH is active and tries to reconnect to localhost but it is not restarting the SSH session, so I'm wondering if there is another way to reconnect the SSH connection without having to close and restart the session.

> Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: No, there's no `tmux` for MySQL sessions. If the ssh tunnel is terminated, the session is ended.